# how to configure shared iPad for Apple Business Manager?

Tags: ipad

I was checking for a **Shared iPad** for **Apple Business Manager**.
I know **Shared iPad** working very cool for Apple School Manager.

I was Checking [Apple Business Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/apple-business-manager/asm6a88f692e/1/web/1) but there is not much information on this.

I need to share iPad means like in Apple School Manager one iPad is shared with multiple Students the same Like that I need in Apple Business Manager

Comment: What are you sharing? The iPad? The Apple ID? Both using the same system login?

Comment: @SolarMike I need to share iPad means like in Apple School Manager 1 iPad is shared with multiple Student the same Like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving the answer to my question because I get the answer from [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251017776) which I also asked on [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251017776) 
there I got the answer.

So the answer is till now it's **not possible**. it's only available for **Apple School Manager**

[image]